# JBoss perform user management from client

Tags: jboss

I want to perform user management tasks like 'create user' or 'change password' on JBoss 7.1 Server from client side and I was thinking of achieving this by deploying a little Webservice that would offer those functions. So i was looking at the JBoss Management API and also at the Command-line public API, but I didn't find any way of accessing those functions. Can anyone tell me if there is a way of achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know if JBoss does provide this function, I accomplished the task with getting the Configuration Folder with `System.getProperty("jboss.server.config.dir")` and editing into application-users.property.